# JMETER : How to load page response completely

Tags: jmeter

While im recording a site response code loading fully and while replaying that complete response code is not loading properly. so, how can i do overcome this

Comment: JMeter is not a browser to load and render the response content like a browser. It is load testing tool which will hit http requests to server and will get the response back. nothing more than this.

Answer (score 0):

After recording, correlation should be done before executing the load test:

http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html

hope this will help.